# Search function in Flask

Tags: python, search, flask

I have a problem with my search. At the moment i am trying to write a small receipe portal and i am trying to search words in tables `user`,`category` and `recipe`. When i write some word, i receive an error message:

> Bad request. The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

I suppose, that problem stays in my function `search`, but i dont see it.

```
@app.route("/search", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    cursor = g.con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM nutzer, kategorien, rezepte WHERE Nutzername OR Titel = %s', (request.form["search"],))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('Results.html', result = result)
```

```html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
<table border="1">
    {% for i in result %}
        <tr><td>{{ i.1 }}</td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

HTML Code of the searchbar

```
    <form action="search">
        <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="suchen" value="{{ request.form.search}}" required />
        <button>finden</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: post the error traceback

Comment: I dont have it. Only "400 Bad request".

Comment: request.form() implies the POST method, while the default one is GET. You should either check request.method and use request.args() in the case of GET, or modify the form with method="POST". You do need to see the server log to perform meaningful debugging.

Comment: @MikeBessonov you should really post that as an answer

Comment: @olly_uk thanks, I will give it a shot. There are probably more issues out there...

Comment: Unrelated, but there's something wrong with your SQL query WHERE clause - you probably want something like "WHERE Nutzername = %s OR Titel = %s"

Answer (score 2):

request.form() implies the POST method, while the default one is GET. You should either check request.method and use request.args() in the case of GET, or add the argument `method="POST"` to the `<form>` (and leave POST as the only accepted method in `@app.route()`.

Comment: for a search view, you definitly want to use GET (a search is idempotent, and using GET allow users to bookmark the search).

Answer (score 0):

I think your form action has to point to your search endpoint.

```
<form action="{{ url_for(search) }}">
  <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="suchen" value="" required />
  <button>finden</button>
</form>
```